# How can a fragment announce itself on launch in Android Talkback?

Tags: android, android-fragments, talkback, accessibility

I want `Fragment` to announce itself on launch in Android Talkback. `Activity` does announce itself when added 'android:label' on the activity tag in AndroidManifest file. How can I do that for `Fragment`?

Comment: I didn't known `android:label` gets announced automatically—thanks, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use one of the Fragment lifecycle methods to announce it yourself.

Fragments don't have an intrinsic title, and since they're basically Views + logic, it seems reasonable that the system can't predict when it would be appropriate to announce a newly added Fragment.

Something like overriding `onCreateView(View view, ...)` and then calling `view.announceForAccessibility("title of my fragment")` would work.

Comment: Thing is, calling `announceForAccessibility` in `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` does *not* seem to work. Similarly if you try it in  `onResume` of an Activity: curiously, the label only gets announced when returning to my app, not when first opening the activity.

Comment: @Jonik yes you're right, I've since seen this - the view must be attached to the window for this to work. I wonder if finding the `android.R.id.content` view and using that to announce would work at any point.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with the same and the accepted answer did not work for me.
I had a look at the lifecycle of a fragment and decided to call it on the last method before the fragment became active: onResume

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    rootView.announceForAccessibility("title of my fragment");
}
```